# React Router - dynamic routing setup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-routing

I am sure I am missing something simple here but can't get my routes configured properly.

I get this error:

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'children' is marked as required in 'App', but its value is 'undefined'.
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router`

Here is my basic setup:

**./index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**./routes/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
  path: '/',
  component: require('../components/app'),
  indexRoute: require('./home')
};
```

**./routes/home.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('../components/home'));
    });
  }
};
```

**./components/app/index.jsx**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

const App = props => (
  <section>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <section>{props.children}</section>
  </section>
);

App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

**./components/home/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => (
  <section>
    <h3>Home</h3>
  </section>
);

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need need to specify `.default` when requiring a file using export. Home will be undefined without it hence the error

**./routes/home.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {

        // need to specify .default when requiring a file using export
        cb(null, require('../components/home').default);
        });
    }
};
```